# What does EMF actually mean?

Tags: potential, voltage, definition, electromagnetic-induction

After studying EMF in DC circuits I realised that EMF is just the potential difference between cell terminals in an open circuit.

But then I was introduced to Faraday's laws of electromagnetic induction where induced EMF due to a changing magnetic flux is discussed.

What I don't get is: is this induced EMF also here a potential difference, as it was in the above case? If so, then where is the positive build-up and where is the negative build-up in, say, a simple coil, which provide the potential difference?

Can we in a circuit with an induced EMF have distinct potential differences between any two points similar to DC circuits?

Comment: Please edit your question to remove uncommon abbreviations (like pd and ve), and change common ones to all caps (e.g. EMF).  Use *whole words* so that your question will be readable.

Comment: I don't think it's quite correct that emf is just potential difference. The potential difference of a cell is due to the electric field of the charge *separated* by the emf of the cell. This potential difference due to the separated charge is a measure of the strength of the emf of the cell. For example, from the Wikipedia article [Electromotive force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force), we have:  *"Inside a source of emf that is open-circuited, the conservative electrostatic field created by separation of charge exactly cancels the forces producing the emf. (continued)...*

Comment: *... Thus, the emf has the same value but opposite sign as the integral of the electric field aligned with an internal path between two terminals A and B of a source of emf in open-circuit condition (the path is taken from the negative terminal to the positive terminal to yield a positive emf, indicating work done on the electrons moving in the circuit)"*

Comment: Roughly, EMF is the amount of work needed to move a unit charge through a field *that is not due to a collection of static charges*.   It's similar to electric potential, but not conservative.  I'm sure someone will give a better definition, but that might do until then.